# What is the exact procedure to represent any positive integer '$n$' in the $m-adic$ form?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

I've just started graduate number theory.This seems to be an elementary question,but i'm not getting exact procedure to represent any positive integer '$n$' in the $m-adic$ form.

In particular,what is the $2-adic$ representation of $100$?

> REFERENCE-Methods in Number Theory by Melvyn B.Nathanson

I'll be grateful for any help.

Thank you!

Comment: You mean, convert to base $m$? To convert a positive integer $n$ to base $m$, first figure out the exponent $e$ so that $m^e\le n<m^{e+1}$. Then to compute the first digit $d$ you divide $n/m^e$ and round down. To get the rest of the digits you repeat this on the difference $n-dm^e$. To understand why this works, try to see what's happening during the procedure when the base is $m=10$.

Comment: Just as @arctictern says, the $m$-adic representation is *nothing but* the $m$-ary expansion. Only good for positive integers, while for negatives, you have to do something else.

Comment: I've extended my answer below... it goes beyond what you asked.

Answer (score 1):

The p-adic *absolute value* is the inverse of $m$ to the power the number of powers of $m$ in n, so the 2-adic absolute value of $100$ is:

$\frac{1}{4}$

Because

$100 = 2^2\times5^2$

$\implies \lvert100\rvert_2= \frac{1}{4}$

However it is confusing because there is also a full p-adic representation, which is the number written in base $m$.  However... where we usually allow decimals to repeat to the right, in the p-adics we allow these numbers to repeat to the left. So in base 10 we can write minus 1 as:

$\bar9999_{10} = \bar9_{10}$

Because if we add 1 to that, using normal hindu-arabic arithmetic the ones carry to infinity giving us infinite zeroes, which is simply zero. This simple fact reveals the way in which p-adics discard to some degree the "magnitude" of a divergent series, but retain the congruence information.

The same goes in any base $m$, that if we write a recurring number:

$\overline{m-1}_m$, it is equal to minus 1.

So in the 2-adics: $\bar11111=-1$

This creates an issue for any compound $m$, that for any given number we can always find a 2nd representation of the same number; a problem which does not occur for prime-adics, hence $p-adics$ because this is why we always use a prime $p$.

Which leads us on to the 2-adic representation of 100 which is simply $1100100_2$

What's the point? You may ask.  That's just 100 in base 2.  Well it gets more interesting when you start using negative numbers and fractions because then the p-adics start to encode congruence information in a way that's really helpful in number theory.

To construct a negative whole number, continue to subtract from $-1$, so $\overline{1}0_2$ is minus $2$, and $\overline{1}00_2$ is minus $4$.

To construct a fraction, the negative of a proper fraction is the same number recurring to the left of the decimal point.  So if in normal base 10 $$\frac{6}{7}=0.\overline{857142}$$ then the 10-adic version of $-\frac{6}{7}$ is: $$\overline{857142}_{10}$$

You can add $1$ as normal to yield $\frac{1}{7}$ in p-adic form as $$\overline{285714}3_{10}$$ (note the 3 isn't under the line as it doesn't repeat).

You already have $\overline{999999}=-1$

And if you add either of those forms to $\frac{1}{7}$ you will find you are back at $-\frac{6}{7}$.

Comment: yes sorry, already corrected.

Comment: :In my text book it is given that ,2-adic representaion of 100 is $1.2^2+1.2^5+1.2^6$.I'm not getting how it'll follow from your answer.

Comment: @SANDEEPSINGH it's just a different notation. Look at where the 1's are in my binary version. They are in the 3rd, 6th and 7th positions.  Each is worth $2^{n-1}$ where n is the position. I have used normal base 2 notation while your book has spelt out the value of each non zero digit in that number. Both mean 64 plus 32 plus 4.

Comment: $1.2^2=1\times 2^2=4$ ... their notation has the potential to confuse.

Comment: @SANDEEPSINGH Sorry I just corrected a missing minus sign in the answer.